# R nested for loops returns unexpected results

Tags: r, nested-loops

**Background**
I am using nested loops in R to exclude users' overlapping session data from a mobile app. As I cannot share the data, I am using the *flights* data frame from the package *nycflights13* in which I managed to replicate the problem as well.

**Goal**: Exclude all flights which depart from the same destination and overlap time-wise (are in the air at the same time). Among the overlapping flights, choose always the one with the highest flight number (in the original data it makes sense).

**Problem**: I end up with only 12 flights instead of an intended few thousands. Besides painful inefficiency, can you see where's the problem?

**Required packages to reproduce the problem**: tidyverse, [nycflights13][1]

**Our "solution"**:

```
# data (flights from package nycflights13)
df_flights <- flights

df_flights2 <- df_flights %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  filter(carrier == "MQ") %>% # to decrease running time, just a piece of the data
  mutate(
    unique_n_day = as.factor(as.numeric(date(time_hour))), # creating unique number for a day to loop over
    dest = as.factor(dest),
    air_time = air_time*60) # converting to seconds
    

flight_list <- list()

## loop

for (i in levels(df_flights2$dest)){
  df_dest <- df_flights2[df_flights2$dest == i,]
  
  for (d in levels(df_dest$unique_n_day)){
    df_day <- df_dest[df_dest$unique_n_day == d,]
    
    for(n in 1:nrow(df_day)){
      
      df <- df_day[df_day$time_hour >= df_day$time_hour[n] & 
                 df_day$time_hour <= df_day$time_hour[n] +  df_day$air_time[n],]
      
      if (nrow(df) >= 1){
        flight_list[[n]] <- df[which(df$flight==max(df$flight))[1],]
        
      }else(d <- "I know it is silly") # max() complains when the df is empty-> if statement 
    }  
  }
}
# unlisting
fulldata_flight <- do.call("rbind", flight_list)

# dropping duplicated values 
fulldata_flight_clean <- distinct(fulldata_flight)
```

**EDIT:**
If looking for a function returning overlapping intervals, then I recommend using *data.table::foverlaps()* function as the solution below do not catch everything perfectly.
[1]: https://github.com/hadley/nycflights13

Comment: Are you using `lubridate::date` in the `unique_n_day` line?

Comment: I am confused by the phrasing in "Exclude all flights which depart from the same destination and overlap time-wise (are in the air at the same time). Among the overlapping flights, choose always the one with the highest flight number (in the original data it makes sense)." Do you want to include all flights except ones which overlap in time and destination AND don't have the highest flight number?

Comment: What if flight A overlaps with flight B which overlaps with flight C, but flight C doesn't overlap with flight A. Which ones would you look at to pick the highest flight number?

Comment: I'm not sure about the specifics of what you want, but I expect a non-equi join with data.table will be 10-100x faster than this method.

Comment: Is it unimportant for your use case that this seems to ignore overlapping sessions which start on different days? If the sessions are short I can imagine that's negligible.

Comment: 1) Exactly, lubridate::date () was used (I thought it is loaded automatically with tidyverse but it isn't).

Comment: 3) A, B, C flights - That's an excellent point. I checked the users' data and the situation you described doesn't occur there. However, it certainly does in the flight data. I haven't noticed this inconsistency.

Comment: 4) Exactly as you say, it is negligible.

Comment: 2) Let's think of the original data. We have a data frame wherein one row corresponds to single mindfulness session and users have always more than one session. Often, one user had multiple time concurrent sessions which we know is a non-sense. We want to keep all sessions/flights but if they are two or more overlapping sessions from the same user, then we want only the longest one/ the largest flight number. I ended up using foverlaps() from the data.table. Thank you for your questions, it helped to look at the problem from a new perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing `n` in line 29 of your code:

```
flight_list[[n]] <- df[which(df$flight==max(df$flight))[1],]
```

However, `n` iterates over the flights per day and destination, which happen to be 14 max (line 23):

```
for(n in 1:nrow(df_day))
```

This means results are overwritten.
Just set the final list iterator outside the first loop and advance it manually after adding to the list.

In addition, by first identifying all valid destination and day combinations you can get rid of one for-loop. See full code below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
library(lubridate)
# data (flights from package nycflights13)
df_flights <- flights

df_flights2 <- df_flights %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  filter(carrier == "MQ") %>% # to decrease running time, just a piece of the data
  mutate(
    unique_n_day = as.factor(as.numeric(date(time_hour))), # creating unique number for a day to loop over
    dest = as.factor(dest),
    air_time = air_time*60) # converting to seconds


flight_list <- list()
list_id <- 1 # Results list iterator

# Get all valid destination and day combinations
dest_day_comb <- df_flights2 %>%
  group_by(dest, unique_n_day) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup()

## loop
for (i in seq(nrow(dest_day_comb))) {
  current_comb <- dest_day_comb[i,]
  df_day <- df_flights2 %>%
    filter(dest == current_comb$dest,
           unique_n_day == current_comb$unique_n_day)
  # Since we are only iterating over valid combinations, there is no need to check if df_day is > 0.
  for(n in 1:nrow(df_day)){
    
    df <- df_day[df_day$time_hour >= df_day$time_hour[n] & 
                 df_day$time_hour <= df_day$time_hour[n] +  df_day$air_time[n],]
    
    flight_list[[list_id]] <- df[which(df$flight==max(df$flight))[1],] # Using the list_id to add to the results list.
    # Info: This creates duplicates since valid solutions are added nrow(df) times.
    # However, these duplicates are removed later on.
    list_id <- list_id + 1
  }  
}

# unlisting
fulldata_flight <- do.call("rbind", flight_list)

# dropping duplicated values 
fulldata_flight_clean <- distinct(fulldata_flight)
```

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for: neater, faster, and working, thanks. The question concerning a mistake in our implementation was answered, however, in further exploration, I have noticed that the way how overlapping sessions are defined is too inclusive. Instead of comparing time hour, I eventually used **foverlaps** function from data.table. Should I update your solution or keep it as it, given the loop runs?

Comment: The answer should match the question so others can understand it without working through the comments. So either update the question and the answer (which is somehow useless since the main question was about the error in the loop) or keep both as they are. Maybe you can add a comment to the questions regarding the foverlaps solution.